# Get result as object not array in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this simple sql query

```
$orders=DB::table('carts')
                - 
 ->join('prod_suppliers','carts.prod_supplier_id','=','prod_suppliers.id')
 ->join('tickets','carts.ticket_id','=','tickets.id') 
 ->distinct()                                
  ->select(
     'suppliers.id as supplier_id',
     'suppliers.supplier',
     'suppliers.house_no_street_no',
     'barangays.brgy_name',                        
     'suppliers.city_id',
     'tickets.id',
     'tickets.ticket_no',                                                                                            

    )                        
  ->get();  

dd($orders);
```

i want my result to be an object but im getting result as an array

```
Collection {#525 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▶]
}
```

what is the best way i can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a collection of **Order** objects.  The `dd()` shows array, but those are objects inside that array. If you loop on the `$orders` variable, you will have ability to use object notation to get the fields you need.

For example:

```
foreach($objects as $object){
    echo ($object->id); // or whatever field you need from the $order object
}
```

This is actually where Laravel really shines though - it has a fantastic model system.   Using a model to pull the data through a simple Eloquent query, along with any relationships you need, might make your like far easier.